# What is the purpose of repeated words?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

I came across 2 sentences that include the repeated words.

1) **流れ流れた**ドヤ街で へんなおやじにつきまとわれて...

2) マスコミ利用し世間からせしめた黄金百万両！　**御用御用**とむらがる捕り手あたるをさいわいぶったおし...

I would like to know if there is any meaning other than their literal meanings.　Or is the purpose of repeated words just emphasizing their original meaning?

Answer (score 6):

1) This kind of repeated verbs express the action that happened repeatedly, or for a long time. The effect is not very different from how English speakers say "He ran and ran" and such. In addition, this 流れ流れた has 7 morae, and you can see this forms a good 七五調 rhythm like [*waka*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waka_(poetry)).

> 流れ流れた(7) - ドヤ街で(5) - へんなおやじに(7) - つきまとわれて(7) ...

2) 御用! (or 御用だ!) is a phrase which was actually shouted by [policemen in the Edo period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edo_period_police) (well, [at least in dramas today](http://news.livedoor.com/article/image_detail/5430414/?img_id=1817082)). So 御用 is naturally repeated, as shown in [the dictionary example](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/82495/meaning/m0u/) below:

> ３ 捕り手が官命で犯人を捕らえること。また、**そのときのかけ声**。転じて、警察につかまること。**「―、―、神妙にしろ」**「―になる」